# arrayformula is not expanding (I'm out of ideas)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[EDIT]

A bit more explaining because the solution given by @z.. is not working and I'm sure it because I haven't explained well.

I have a Google Sheet named Watchlist, and one named stockPrices. In `Watchlist`:

- `A1:A` contains a list of stock tickers
- Column `AV` has some helper cells, with precalculated values, for instance todays date, and today 5 years ago
- Each ticker from `A1:A` has a column in the `stockPrices` sheet. Column `AL` gives the column index for each ticker in `stockPrices`
- Ignore column `B` for now

Watchlist:

```
    --+-------+----------+ ... +------+ ... +------------+
      |   A   |     B    | ... |  AL  | ... |     AV     |
    --+-------+----------+ ... +------+ ... +------------+
    1 | AAPL  |  150.12  | ... | 2    | ... | 05.01.2024 | todays date
    2 | MSFT  |  344.01  | ... | 4    | ... | 05.01.2019 | date 5 years ago
    3 | KO    |   55.12  | ... | 3    | ... | 6267       | todays row in stockPrices
    4 | PEP   |   70.54  | ... | 330  | ... | 4962       | row 5 yrs ago in stockPrices
    5 | TSLA  |          | ... |      | ... |            |
    6 | SPCE  |          | ... |      | ... |            |
    --+-------+----------+ ... +------+ ... +------------+
```

- In `Watchlist` cells `AV5` and `AV7` I have todays date, and the date 5 years ago from today. `AL3` gives the column index for a ticker (in this case the ticker in `A3`)

In `stockPrices`:

- `A2:A` gives dates from `01.01.2000` to `31.12.2024`
- Columns `B` and further have the historical stock prices for the tickers from `Watchlist`. See that the column index from `WatchList!AL` corresponds with the columns for the respective tickers
- In each ticker column (for instance `B`, there are 3 possible values: a decimal (being a historical price), NA (if no price was available for that day) and (empty), meaning for future dates
- Currently, there are 330 tickers in `Watchlist`, corresponding to 330 columns in `stockPrices` (`B` to `LR`)
- Note that the rows `6267` and `4962`, taken from `Watchlist!AV3` and `Watchlist!AV4`, respectively, hold the data for todays date and 5 years ago

stockPrices:

```
    -----+------------+----------+-------+--------+ ... +-------+
         |     A      |     B    |   C   |    D   |     |  LR   |
    -----+------------+----------+-------+--------+ ... +-------+
    1    | Date       |  AAPL    | KO    | MSFT   | ... | PEP   |
    2    | 01.01.2000 |  0.92    | 6.21  | 23.32  | ... | 11.54 |
    3    | 02.01.2000 |  1.11    | 6.54  | 23.12  | ... | 10.76 |
    4    | 03.01.2001 |  NA      | 7.00  | 24.11  | ... | 10.53 |
    .    | ...        |  ...     | ...   | ...    | ... | ...   |
    4962 | 05.01.2019 |  30.51   | 18.21 | 100.21 | ... | 60.43 |
    .    | ...        |  ...     | ...   | ...    | ... | ...   |
    5571 | 26.05.2021 |  130.13  | 53.73 | 180.65 | ... | 70.54 |
    .    | ...        |  ...     | ...   | ...    | ... | ...   |
    6626 | 04.01.2024 |  150.12  | 55.12 | 340.54 | ... | 55.54 |
    6267 | 05.01.2024 |  149.74  | 52.24 | 344.01 | ... | 56.00 |
    .    | ...        |  ...     | ...   | ...    | ... | ...   |
    6625 | 28.12.2024 |          | ...   |        | ... |       |
    6626 | 29.12.2024 |          | ...   |        | ... |       |
    6627 | 30.12.2024 |          | ...   |        | ... |       |
    6628 | 31.12.2024 |          | ...   |        | ... |       |
    -----+------------+----------+-------+--------+ ... +-------+
```

What I am trying to achieve in `Watchlist!B1`, is a formula that expands downwards to calculate for each ticker the maximum price between 2 dates, in this case today (`05.01.2024`) and 5 years ago (`05.01.2019`). These dates are given in Watchlist `AV1` and `AV2`. I also have available the row numbers in `stockPrices` that hold data for these dates. The values from column `AV` can be used as input for formulas. The desired result is in the `Watchlist:B` column in the beginning of this post.

I now use the following formula to calculate in column `B` for each ticker the maximum price in the last 5 years:

```
=MAX(
  FILTER(
    INDEX(stockPrices!$B$2:$LR, , AL1), 
    stockPrices!$A$2:$A<>"", 
    stockPrices!$A$2:$A>=$AV$2, 
    stockPrices!$A$2:$A<=$AV$1, 
    stockPrices!$A$2:$A<>0, 
    stockPrices!$A$2:$A<>""
  )
)
```

If I drag this formula down, it works for all tickers, but I'm looking to turn this into a formula that does not need to be dragged down.

@z.. suggested the following (adjusted to fit the example data), but again, it did not work. The error I go was *"Error. FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 6627. column count: 1. Actual row count: 1, column count: 1."* I hope I have explained the situation better now.

```
 =MAP(AL1:AL,LAMBDA(idx,MAX(
  FILTER(
    INDEX(stockPrices!B2:LR, , idx), 
    stockPrices!A2:A<>"", 
    stockPrices!A2:A>=AV2, 
    stockPrices!A2:A<=AV1, 
    stockPrices!A2:A<>0, 
  )
)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ARRAYFORMULA` function is designed to enable arrays, the fact that in many cases it allows a formula to expand over adjacent cells is a consequence of this. However, that's not really its purpose. Its purpose is to allow us to iterate over each value in an array when we provide it as an argument to a function that **by default does not expect arrays**, it doesn't work the way many people expect when it's used with functions that by default expect arrays. (`FILTER` and `MAX` in your case)

You have to use `MAP` to get the formula to expand:

```cpp
=MAP(AL3:AL,LAMBDA(idx,MAX(
  FILTER(
    INDEX(stockPrices!B2:AAX,,idx), 
    stockPrices!A2:A>=AV7, 
    stockPrices!A2:A<=AV5 
  )
)))
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but I don't understand what you mean by replacing AV5, AV7 and AL3 with corresponding arrays. All 3 are just values (2 dates and 1 columindex number) taken from a cell. Could you please elaborate? Or do you mean ixd is just one value (AL3) in the range/array "$AL3:AL"? This I can understand; the column number is different for each ticker. But the dates (AL5, AL7) stay the same.

Comment: @Pr0no, if column AL is the only column that contains the value that changes, then that's the only column we have to put as argument to MAP. See updated answer.

Comment: I also removed the last FILTER condition `stockPrices!A2:A<>""` because you already have it.

Comment: Your formula did not work for me, and I'm sure it's because I didn't explain myself well. I have updated the opening post, with more detailed information. Can I ask you to please have a look?

Comment: @Pr0no, please share a sample sheet with example of your data and desired result. You can [Make an anonymous sample document](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform)

Comment: please see here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HM0tI3u3ewLNS8RPTbOyzvO1yEhffJnbjeMo1meg8mQ/edit#gid=0

Comment: @Pr0no, which cell has the formula with the error?

Comment: Apologies, I forgot the formula! It is in C2, and the error is: "Error FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 6627. column count: 1. Actual row count: 1, column count: 1." Coincidentally, 6627 is the row count of stockPrices sheet.

Comment: There was en extra comma after the last condition. I updated the formula.

Comment: Amazing. I see that it works, so will mark your answer as correct, but might come back to you tomorrow if I have any questions if that's ok.